# Appropriate use of Azure AD Groups to manage permissions

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory

I am creating an application that uses Azure AD user groups to grant permissions to specific resources. For example, a particular set of documents can only be accessed by users in specific groups. The application receives the group ids as claims on the JWT and ensures that only documents assigned to groups in the claims are visible.

Now, the question is how to manage groups correctly in Azure AD. When users are assigned to a group become a member of that group and any groups that group is nested in. This seems to imply that my group nesting should be the reverse of the tree structure I would like. Something like this:

Admin --> member of --> Group with most access --> member of --> group with less access --> member of --> group with least access.

To me this seems backwards but it provides the correct access rights to users added to each group.

Am I way off base here or is this a reasonable way to manage access rights with AD groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JoyWang already covered some good points in answer above. Here are some additional considerations. *Disclaimer:* Due to nature of question, my answer here is mostly opinion and learning from some cases. Idea is to share how I have seen groups getting used along with some related info.

1. Are the groups specific to your application or more general purpose? Group membership and nested groups are usually used to organize users & groups logically/intuitively rather than design permissions for specific application

   Many times Azure AD Groups are used by more than one application and may have a lifetime longer than any one specific application you're developing.

   The way you are thinking about nesting groups based on which one has more access v/s less access you're probably concerned about only one particular application that you're developing and thinking about a group's access to this application. This approach will work out if the groups you plan to create are also very application specific and will NOT be used for any other purpose.

   Example1: Your application is a blogging app and groups you create in Azure AD are Viewer, Contributor and Admin. (Admin > Contributor > Viewer)
   Example2: You have an enterprise using Azure AD and groups organize users logically, say deparatment wise Marketing, Human Resources, Engineering etc.

   So, the way you describe nested groups based on lower access permissions to higher, it will technically work out for a simpler scenario like in Example1 but not for Example2 where groups are more general purpose.

   Many times general purpose groups already exist and you're expected to reuse them rather than create new ones for your application which require new assignments/membership all over again, but this may or may not be applicable in your specific case.

   Also, there can be multiple people managing these groups and their membership so any design/organization pattern you come up with **should give importance to intuitiveness** even if you have to sacrifice minor application specific efficiency sometimes.

   In my opinion, you can look at both flat or nested groups.. if it makes sense from an organization of users and groups standpoint, not just access permissions. Another fictious example: `Marketing` Group can have a member group like `Marketing Content Approvers` because it's a subset of Marketing people.
2. Do consider [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

   They are specific to an application, tied to it's manifest and can be available to you as part of claims in token.

   There can be situations like individual resource based access where you want to give permissions to a specific resource where Application Roles may or may not make sense and you still need to rely on groups or users directly. In any case, it's another helpful option available to you.
3. Managing Groups (as you've asked about this in comments)

   Take a look at [Self Service Group Management Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-self-service-management#self-service-group-management-scenarios) (Delegated v/s Self-service) and also [Dynamic Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-create-rule) for dynamic membership rules based on attributes (requires Premium license though).

Comment: Thank you Rohit, your examples of how groups are used differently provided some useful context for me. Also the links to self service group management and dynamic groups were also helpful. My particular use case is closer to the blogging app then the enterprise app but there is also some cross over. Additionally a significant amount of my access control is for individual resources which limits the usefulness of roles. Again, thank you for the response it has been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In AAD, the permissions of a member in the groups depend on the biggest permission of the group which he is a member of. For example, group A can access a resource and group B can't access it, the man is both in group A and B, then he will be able to access the resource.

> To me this seems backwards but it provides the correct access rights to users added to each group.

Let we call the three groups as A,B,C, the permission of them is A > B >C. Obviously, if you add A to B, the permissions of A and B both have not been affected. But if you add B to A, the members in A or B will both have the biggest permission, it is no what you want. The same with B and C. This is why it provides the correct access rights to users added to each group as you said.

So in my personal opinion, seems no need to use nested groups, just use three groups with different permissions, it's enough.

Comment: Yes, just using untested groups seems simpler for managing access rights. However, I was also thinking of using the nesting as a management tool. I could use the nesting as a way to keep track of associated groups. Is there some better way to keep track of groups? Seems simple flat list of groups will be difficult to manage. How do other people organizes groups?

Comment: @EliPulsifer Your question seems to be too broad, what the most I can do is to let you know the rule of group and give you some personal opinions. I don’t know what is easy and difficult to manage the groups for you. For the specific ways to manage the groups in the production environment, it should depend on yourself.

Comment: Agreed, its a broad question and dependent on my particular use case.